# stop already playing sound with javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following function to play a sound when 
a div is hovered

```
function playsound() {
    var snd = new Audio();
    snd.src = 'snd/ring.mp3';
    snd.play();
}

// Play sound on mouseover
$('.navigation a').hover(function () {
    playSound();
    $(this).find('img').animateRotate(-360, 1000);
});
```

the problem is that when the mouseleaves the link, it replays the sound again.
i want it to play it once and also when the mouse leaves all sounds should be stopped.
How can this be done ?

Comment: Read the documentation for the function you're calling.

Comment: hover() isn't mouseover().  If you give hover() only one function, it will use it for both mouseover and mouseout events.

Answer (score 1):

The `hover()` function addds handlers for mouseenter and mouseleave.

You want to handle `mouseenter` only.